# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jodd.Jodd.init(Ljava/lang/Class;)V

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror, jodd

I am trying to use the `Jodd-http version 3.6.6` library in a simple application. The application runs fine on a test machine which has `java 1.8` installed but when I try to run the same application on another machine with `java 1.7` it throws this excption.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jodd.Jodd.init(Ljava/lang/Class;)V

is this version of `jodd-http` is not compatible with `java 1.7`?

Answer (score 1):

Jodd modules are distributed in two flavors:

1 .as a single bundle jar, that contain all Jodd modules in one distribution archive.

2. separate jar for each module.

So Jodd may be used on any platform where there is a suitable Java 7+ runtime environment.

Comment: Excellent answer! Just little add-on, up to v3.6.6, Jodd was working on any Java 5+ environment, starting from v3.7.0 it will work on Java 7+.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be related to java version, but to existance of jodd libraries - are you sure you have `jodd-core` jar in your classpath?

Because `jodd-http` can't work without `jodd-core`:) And from your exception it looks like only `jodd-http` jar is present in the classpath; but not `jodd-core`.

Can you check this please?

I don't know if you use maven repo (jCentar or Maven Central), but it would be good so all this dependencies can be loaded automatically.

EDIT:

Check **httpclient** example in the https://github.com/oblac/jodd-quickstart

EDIT:
Check the classloaders - if they see the `Jodd` class (or any class from `jodd-core`); maybe the classloader for some reason dont see it; or there are multiple different versions of `jodd-http` on the classpath.

Comment: yes, I am using the central maven repo. Also it is the same JAR I am using on both machines :(